# internet explorer 11 Authoraization Error in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have created a pdf viewer component in angular 4 and I am getting authorization error while opening the doc. here is the HTML templet and I am also using the DomSanitizer to bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl.

I also enabled the protected mode in Adobe pdf reader. It is working in all the remaining browsers.
thanks in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2eKP.png)

Comment: <object *ngIf="url" [data]="url" type="application/pdf" style="height: 781px">
 
</object>

Comment: Here is the simple plunker example https://plnkr.co/edit/vn3V2ccKAGVzHGPGKadE?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer can solve this problem it works both in IE and chrome.